# Operator (+) vs Left Outer Join

Tags: sql, oracle

i have the following sql query:

```
select d.c3
from table1 a,
     table2 b,
     table3 e,
     table4 d
where a.c1(+) = b.c1 AND d.c1(+) = e.c1 and e.c2 (+) = b.c2
```

I would like to change the plus operator (+) to a left join or any other join operator.

Any help please?

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: Great idea! Show us what you've tried!

Comment: how do i transform this query since i have multiple joins on same tables?

Comment: i tried:    select d.c3 from table1 a left outer join table2 b on a.c1=b.c1, 
table4 d left outer join table3 e on d.c1 = e.c1,
table3 e2 left outer join table2 b2 on e2.c2 = b2.c2
where e2.id = e.id and b2.id = b.id;         but it didn't work :(

Comment: I believe it is: `SELECT d.c3 FROM table2 b LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 a ON ( a.c1 = b.c1 ) LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 e ON ( b.c2 = e.c2 ) LEFT OUTER JOIN table4 d ON ( e.c1 = d.c1 )`

Comment: it didn't work too @MT0

Comment: The explain plan shows that they are identical. Compare `EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
select d.c3
from table1 a,
     table2 b,
     table3 e,
     table4 d
where a.c1(+) = b.c1 AND d.c1(+) = e.c1 and e.c2 (+) = b.c2;
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display('plan_table',null,'typical'));` to `EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
select d.c3
from table2 b
     LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 a
     ON (b.c1 = a.c1)
     LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 e
     ON (e.c2 = b.c2)
     LEFT OUTER JOIN table4 d
     ON ( e.c1 = d.c1 );
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display('plan_table',null,'typical'));` and they are the same.

Comment: but the first query returned 1 lign while the second one did'nt return any lign...@MT0

Comment: When you reply to someone's solution, it isn't helpful to only state it "didn't work". There are hundreds of reasons a query can be considered "not working". Do you get an error, if so what is the error. Do you get unexpected results, if so provide an [mcve]. Also, code in a comment is very hard to read, if you want to provide code or data please edit your question to include it. Help us help you!